# The contradiction in KPSS and HEGY test

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality, unit-root, kpss-test

I am new to this field and I have a question.

I have a seasonal rainfall dataset and I want to apply SARIMA model on it.

For this purpose, I applied the KPSS tests and I got the following output:

```
Warning in kpss.test(rainfall, c("Level")) :
  p-value greater than printed p-value

    KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  rainfall
KPSS Level = 0.14231, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.1
```

```
KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity

data:  rainfall
KPSS Trend = 0.13364, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.07289
```

Thus, I accept the null hypothesis and stationarity.

On the other hand, I applied HEGY test to test the regular and seasonal unit root:

```
HEGY test for unit roots
data:  rainfall
        statistic p-value    
t_1       -2.6812  0.1328    
t_2       -2.1006  0.1546    
F_3:4     10.7895   6e-04 ***
F_5:6      7.5133  0.0096 ** 
F_7:8      6.4761  0.0228 *  
F_9:10      6.017  0.0331 *  
F_11:12    4.0907  0.1451    
F_2:12     6.7083   9e-04 ***
F_1:12     6.8704   0.001 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Deterministic terms: constant + trend + seasonal dummies 
Lag selection criterion and order: fixed, 12
P-values: based on response surface regressions
```

The output shows that the system has both regular and seasonal unit root. Which one is true? I attached the ACF and pACF plots of it.

Thank you.

[image: ADF plot of the dataset]

[image: PACF plot of the dataset]